# get member count before accessing server discord

Tags: discord, discord.js

Is there any way to get member count on a discord server before actually accessing to it.
Basically all i have is discord.gg url and i need member count

I.E

```
https://discord.gg/satoshirunners Satoshi Runners Official Collection
https://discord.gg/pd PixelDucks NFT
https://discord.gg/fancybirds Fancy Birds | Play2Earn
https://discord.gg/ksjZmCS8 CIV WAR |
https://discord.gg/hazemonkeynft Haze Monkey Society - Genesis NFT
https://discord.gg/BoldBadgersSquad Bold Badgers Squad | Bold Badgers Squad | Bold Badgers Squad | Bold Badgers Squad |
https://discord.gg/Sula#3470 bubbles(face)
https://discord.gg/AMZeBFSDhr All Spark Space Game
https://discord.gg/CryptoHasbulla CyptoKoksalbaba
https://discord.gg/PAINTHAMSTERNFT PAINT Hamster Nft
https://discord.gg/cryptonewbird avarta101
```

Need to get member's count of each those servers.

Tried with client.guilds.fetch("") but obviously this works only if it's on my server

```
client.guilds.fetch("356230556738125824").then((channel) => {
    console.log(channel)
 }).catch((error) => {
     console.log(error)
 })
```

Comment: *"Is there any way to get member count on a discord server before actually accessing to it"* - getting the member count would require accessing the server... unless you mean the bot joining it

Comment: `client.guilds.fetch` won't do anything if the bot is not inside the guild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible.

```js
client.fetchInvite("yourInvite")
    .then(async invite => {
    const guild = await invite.guild.fetch()

    console.log(guild.memberCount)

})
```