# Getting the member count history of Discord servers?

Tags: discord

For research purposes, I'd love to see the member growth of public Discord servers.

I know that I can get the *current* member count [via the REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71567364/776142) or via [`client.fetchInvite`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71087907/776142), but I am wondering– is there some way at all to get the historic member count data?

The member count information is publicly available and many sites index servers with the current count, but I couldn't find any that show historic data, although it seems like a logical thing to do. Such a site would be sufficient for my purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the history by yourself, saving the member count on a repeat scheduled. There is no endpoint to get this kind of statistics.